# Comments are being covered by sidebar

Tags: bug, comments

Observe:

[image]

The resolution of my monitor is 1280 x 1024.

Comment: What browser? In Firefox 30 on Windows 7, I can't make that happen no matter how narrow I resize the window.

Comment: Clear your browser's cache, something must've gone wrong there, client-side. Even my phone wraps comments properly.

Comment: @Cerbrus Nice call, its fixed. If you care, leave an answer and I'll accept it and if not, I'll do it and leave it up for anyone else if they need it.

Comment: Maybe we need a canonical duplicate with an answer saying *Caching. It's always caching, either client or server-side.*

Comment: @Daniel: Ah, Excellent! I've added a quick answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something probably got messed up in your browser's cache. Clearing the cache should fix the issue.

This [wikihow article](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cache) Has sections that explain how clearing the cache works, for the most popular browsers.

(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> seems to be a common keyboard shortcut)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem (and many similar ones on other sites) in Firefox with a minimum font size set. Without that minimum font size, the problem went away. (See Edit -> Preferences -> Content -> Advanced, and then Minimum font size.) Reloading the page did fix the problem for me too, but only temporarily. After removing the minimum font size, I've never seen it.